# Did the rm project remove itself during early development?

Tags: history, unix

Is it true that Brian Kernighan while developing `rm` accidentally tested the project so that it removed itself? Then, according to story, he had to start over from the beginning because there was no backup. I heard the story from somebody but could not verify that it is true.

Comment: No-one called a single simple program a 'project' ... not sure whether that in itself casts doubt on the story.

Comment: At 9:36am on May 12th the 'rm' project became aware. And promptly deleted itself.

Comment: There is an anecdote in I think one of the Bell Labs papers about `rm -r /`. which would have the effect described.

Comment: It would be an easy mistake to make - remove argv[0] instead of argv[1]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`rm` is attributed to Ken Thompson and Dennis Ritchie (see [the original man page](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/rm), and the attribution in [the Unix history repository](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/386465c52ea4d8f98072bd0f716bacdb4a47aea4)), so the story in question doesn’t ring true.

Brian Kernighan *was* involved with Unix since very early days, so it’s still possible, but he wouldn’t have been a primary developer on `rm`. In any case `rm` is simple enough, [even in V7](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/src/cmd/rm.c), that its deletion wouldn’t have been much of a loss; it wouldn’t have taken long to re-create.

As an aside, specifying `rm` as a script’s shebang allows an executable to [delete itself when executed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280778/86440) (along with any file given as argument).

Comment: It's possible though that in retelling the story from memory the only detail the OP got wrong was who it happened to.

Comment: It's likely that, if one aspect of the story is false, others will be as well :-)